# Boost install error

Tags: boost

I had boost 1.65.1 and also 1.75
i unistalled boost by this command on ubuntu 18.04

`sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-dev`

But on my PC `usr/local/include/boost` in `version.hpp` in that file showing as `1_75`

Well on the other hand `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp | grep "BOOST_LIB_VERSION"` is giving no such file directory

why is that and how to install boost now ?

Comment: The path `/usr/local/include/boost` means that you installed 1,75 from some non-deb source. How you uninstall software depends upon how you installed it -- installing from some non-deb source means that apt-get didn't install 1.75 it and cannot remove it. So, from your description, you still have 1.75 installed. Apt-get could (and apparently did) remove 1.65.

Comment: It would be helpful if i get to know how to remove non-deb source. because i tried not able to remove................ and also correct way to install is also appreciated.

Comment: There are a dozen possible ways to install software without using a deb package. Each is different. Each has it's own different uninstall method. You must specify which method you used. If you followed some online instructions, provide a link to those instructions.

Comment: i have went through this one the thrid one which has 197 (3rd solution)... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578499/how-to-install-boost-on-ubuntu/24086375#24086375